# Accessing real and imaginary parts of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, dolphindb

How can I access the real and imaginary parts of a complex number?

I have a complex number as follows:

```
complex(2, 5)
```

The expected result:

```
2.0+5.0i
```

Answer (score 0):

The data length of the number with complex type is 16 bytes, where the real number stores in the lower 8 bits and the imaginary number in the upper 8 bits.

You can access real number with function `lowDouble`, and imaginary number with function `highDouble`.

```
a=complex(2, 5)
real=lowDouble(a)//obtain the real number 2
imag=highDouble(a)//obtain the imaginary number 5
```